# css class architecture for display

Tags: css

```
.page-setting-popup {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: tomato;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
   height: 120px;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: flex-start;
}
.setting-popup-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
```

I have such code in different place. I don't like that i should use display for almost every block. I think i will be great if I make some class like this.

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Or it should be like this?

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.v-centered {
  align-items:center;
}
.h-centered {
  justify-content: center;
}
.stretch-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I think that the second variant is more flexible. But i need your advice)

```
<div class="page-setting-popup">
  <div class="setting-popup-icon"><span class="zmdi zmdi-time-restore"></span></div>
  <div class="setting-popup-main"><span class="setting-header text-uppercase">Sync. frequency</span>
  <div class="setting-popup-controls">
    <input type="number" min="0"/>
    <button type="submit">V</button>
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share also you relevant HTML Code. without that. we can't help you. also....explain exactly what you want to achieve with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're styling a component, I would put all relevant styles into classes that are specific to the particular component. However, you used `.flex` as an example here, which is pretty generic, so whether factor it out or not is debatable. I wouldn't factor it out though.

Generally, the approach to factor out modifier classes, like `.flex`, `.left`, `right` etc. is pertaining to frameworks like `bootstrap`, since there is no assumption how and where these modifiers will be used. Again, if you're styling a component, you have a good understanding of what styles each of component's part requires and I wouldn't use modifier classes.